# Universal Storyboard Preview - doesn't seem to work properly?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiview, storyboard

i have created a Storyboard where i create universal views for all iphones in portrait form. Simple views work just great, but as soon as you add different views and sub element something goes wrong. Can someone give me some tips what i am doing wrong?

[image]

I will be thankful for every kind of tips/advises how to get rid of this annoying view...

Have a nice sunday!

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution, the problem is that you can set all the measures in percent. But for to count all the sizes, XCode needs minimum 1 measure for width & height. If it gets the size of single element in your design, it can calculate all other sizes.